# Rails 4 strong params get permit from nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

There are several questions for strong params, but I couldn't find any answer for achieving my goal. Please excuse any duplicates (and maybe point me in the right direction).
I'm using strong params in a model that has several 'has_one' associations and nested attributes with 'accepts_attributes_for'.

In my routes I have: (**updated for better understanding**)

```
  resources :organisations do
    resources :contact_details
  end
```

So, i.e. for one associated model I have to use

```
def organisation_params
  params.require(:organisation).permit(:org_reference, :supplier_reference, :org_type, :name, :org_members, :business, :contact_person, contact_detail_attributes: [:id, :contactable_id, :contactable_type, :phone, :fax, :mail, :state, :province, :zip_code, :street, :po_box, :salutation, :title, :last_name, :first_name, :description])
end
```

This works, but I have to retype all my permitted params for each associated model. When I modify my permitted attributes for *contact_details* , I have to change it in several locations (every model that has the polymorphic association).

Is there a way to get the parameter whitelist of *contact_details* and include it into the parent whitelist?

Something like:

```
def organisation_params
  my_params = [:org_reference, :supplier_reference, :org_type, :name, :org_members, :business, :contact_person]
  contact_params = #get permitted params, that are defined in contact_details_controller
  params.require(:organisation).permit(my_params, contact_params)
end
```

I don't want to workaround security, but I had already defined the permitted attributes for the contact_details and don't want to repeat it in every associated "parent" model (because it's exhausting and very prone to stupid mistakes like omitting one attribute in one of several parent models).

Comment: What do you mean with "nested model"?

Comment: I have one "parent" model, that accepts attributes for another model ("nested model"). Perhaps nested resource is a better term?

Comment: Oh ok; I think is better "associated model", or "associated record"

Comment: Ok, I changed it to associated model, hope it clarifies the scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a method defined inside `ApplicationController`, or a shared module:

1. `ApplicationController`:

   ```
   class ApplicationController
     def contact_details_permitted_attributes
       [:id, :contactable_id, :contactable_type, ...]
     end
   end

   class ContactDetailsController < ApplicationController
     def contact_details_params
       params
         .require(contact_details)
         .permit(*contact_details_permitted_attributes)
     end
   end

   class OrganisationsController < ApplicationController
     def organisation_params
       params
         .require(:organisation)
         .permit(:org_reference, ..., 
                 contact_detail_attributes: contact_details_permitted_attributes)
     end
   end
   ```
2. Shared module:

   ```
   module ContactDetailsPermittedAttributes
     def contact_details_permitted_attributes
       [:id, :contactable_id, :contactable_type, ...]
     end
   end

   class ContactDetailsController < ApplicationController
     include ContactDetailsPermittedAttributes

     def contact_details_params
       params
         .require(contact_details)
         .permit(*contact_details_permitted_attributes)
     end
   end

   class OrganisationsController < ApplicationController
     include ContactDetailsPermittedAttributes

     def organisation_params
       params
         .require(:organisation)
         .permit(:org_reference, ..., 
                 contact_detail_attributes: contact_details_permitted_attributes)
     end
   end
   ```

Rails  has even dedicated directories for shared modules, `concerns` inside `app/controllers` and `app/models`; indeed, in your case you should use `app/controllers/concerns`

Comment: that's much (muuuch) better, thanks. Didn't know of concerns so far.. I'm using a concern for nested permissions now, so I can define the whitelisted attributes once and use them in specific "parent" controllers. Sorry, I'm not priviliged to upvote, so unofficial +100 from my side

Comment: Glad to help; I suggest you to learn more about [`ActiveSupport::Concern`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html); I didn't link it in the answer because for your need a shared module is really enough, but it is useful for more complex shared functionalities scenarios

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not.  In your ApplicationController you could have

```
def contact_attributes
  [:id, :contactable_id, :contactable_type, :phone, :fax, 
   :mail, :state, :province, :zip_code, :street, :po_box, 
   :salutation, :title, :last_name, :first_name, :description]
end
```

Then in your organisation_params

```
def organisation_params
  my_params = [:org_reference, :supplier_reference, :org_type, :name, :org_members, :business, :contact_person]

  params.require(:organisation).permit(*my_params, contact_detail_attributes: contact_attributes)
end
```

In some other location you might do...

```
def contact_params
params.require(:contact).permit(*contact_attributes)
end
```